# How to add and remove <option> selected together with <optgroup> from box A to box B?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select

[image]

Referring to the above image, the bold fonts are `<optgroup>` and the list below each is `<option>` inside a multiple select box.The data are fetched from database by ajax.

Now, how do I select the `<option>` but then move to box B the `<optgroup>` as well, so that when I remove the `<option>` from box B, it will go back to it's normal position below appropriate `<optgroup>` please?

script

```
$(".moveSelected1").click(function(){
         $('#show > optgroup > option:selected').remove().appendTo('#show2'); 
    });

    $(".moveSelected2").click(function(){
         $('#show2 > optgroup >option:selected').remove().appendTo('#show'); 
    });
```

html

```
 <select multiple size="10" id="show">

   </select>

<div class="inner_box_wrapper">
                           <div class="controls"> 
                          <!-- <a class="moveAll1">&gt;&gt;</a> -->
                               <a class="moveSelected1">Add &#8594;</a> 
                               <a class="moveSelected2">Remove &#8592;</a> 
                           <!-- <a class="moveAll2" href="#">&lt;&lt;</a>-->
                           </div>
                           </div>
<select multiple size="10" id="show2">

                         </select>
```

I searched in google, but I found the solution nowhere and their explanation is confusing.

PHP file

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"wordblend_db");
//$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects WHERE level_id = '".$q."'";
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_levels,tbl_subjects WHERE tbl_levels.level_id=tbl_subjects.level_id AND tbl_levels.level_id='$q'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $levels=$row['level_name'];
    $levels_id=$row['level_id'];
    $subjects= $row['subject_name'];
    $subjects_id= $row['subject_id'];
   //$_SESSION['subject_by_level'][]=array('lvl_name'=>$levels,'sjt_name'=>$subjects);


 //print_r($_SESSION['subject_by_level']);
    ?>
   <optgroup label="<?php echo $levels;?>" class="<?php echo $q;?>">
       <option value="<?php echo $subjects_id;?>"><?php echo $subjects;?></option>
</optgroup>

    <?php
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add/remove the `optgroups` to the right select box as they're added to/removed from the left box (through `checkbox`). Then it'd be easy to just move the `options` back and forth. If an `optgroup` is empty it'll have `display: none;`. It'll be easy then to handle multiple option/selection.

```
$('.add').on('click', function() {
    $.each($('#show1 option:selected'), function() {
       var og = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        $(this).remove().appendTo('#show2 .' + og); 
    });
    ogVisibility();
});
```

Remove will do the reverse and ogVisibility just hides the empty optgroups:

```
function ogVisibility() {
    $.each($('.show > optgroup'), function() {
        if($(this).html().trim() == "")
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        else
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
    });
}
```

[Here's the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/86crqq5m/2/)

**Edit:**
To have all the options with same category under one optgroup you need to change your php file a little bit:

Order your SQL by the category column:

```
$sql="SELECT * ... ORDER BY level_name";
```

Have a variable to keep the last category and only when it changes generate optgroup tags. So the while will be like:

```
$last_category = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $levels=$row['level_name'];
    ...

    ...
    if($last_category != $levels) {
        $last_category = $levels;
        echo '<optgroup label="' . $levels . '" class="' . $q . '">';
    }

    echo '<option value="' . $subjects_id . '">' . $subjects . '</option>';

    if($last_category != $levels)
        echo '</optgroup>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also help with arranging the <optgroup> and <option> by category? What I mean is, if you look at the image above, Category or <optgroup label> repeats for each option under the same <optgroup>.I've updated by php code for that. Can you tell me how to achieve that please? Thanks

Comment: Do you want all the options with same category to be under one optgroup (i.e. so there's only one optgroup university instead of 3 and 3 options under that category)? 

Or do you want the optgroups to be repeated (like your image) and only one option per optgroup? If so by arranging you mean sorting them like alphabetically or something?

Comment: I want all the options with same category to be under one optgroup.

Comment: thanks again. When I copy paste your fiddle it works but with my code where the data for select box fetched from database, the append and remove not working properly. I think I should try again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the edited part the optgroups are given class `$q`, in the jsfiddle though, I assumed they have a different class and in format of og-shortCountryName (e.g. `og-swe`). So make sure optgroups are given different classes(change `'" class="' . $q` with `'" class="og-' . $levels` .)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75743/discussion-between-sweety-and-samurai).

Comment: is there any solution without making clone(), because <optgroup> & <option> doesn't support "display:none" in Safari 11.1 and IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) on the parent of the selected element `$(el).parent().detach()` but you need to clear the selected state of the items that you transfer.

Alternatively you can also use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML). `$(el).parent().get(0).outerHTML`

I prefer using outerHTML when creating HTML strings that way I can add them up in one single append statement instead of tweaking the DOM with every single iteration.

I've created a small [demo](http://codepen.io/drew-palaganas/pen/rVBvpX) for you to check things out.