# How to add and remove <option> with <optgroup> from box A to box B in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737898/how-to-add-and-remove-option-selected-together-with-optgroup-from-box-a-to-b) and it's perfectly answered, but the problem is it doesn't work properly in Safari like it does in Chrome. In Safari, neither `optgroup` nor `option` support `display: none`.

Is there any way to get it to work like it does in Chrome?

Here is [codepen Snippet](https://codepen.io/wasimv09/full/YdmXaJ)

```js
$.each($('#u-address > optgroup'), function() {
  $(this).clone().empty().appendTo('#m-address');
});
myOgVisibility();
//for dblclick
$('#u-address').dblclick(function() {
  $.each($('#u-address option:selected'), function() {
    var og = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    $(this).remove().appendTo('#m-address .' + og);
    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
  });
  myOgVisibility();
});
$('#m-address').dblclick(function() {
  $.each($('#m-address option:selected'), function() {
    var og = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    $(this).remove().appendTo('#u-address .' + og);
    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
  });
  myOgVisibility();
});

function myOgVisibility() {
  $.each($('.showUniOgrp > optgroup'), function() {
    if ($(this).html().trim() === "") {
      //$(this).detach();
      //$(this).css({'display': 'none'});                
      //$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
      $(this).css({
        'height': '0px !important',
        'display': 'none'
      });
    } else {
      //$(this).appendTo('#m-address');
      //$(this).css({'display': 'block'});
      //$(this).removeAttr('disabled').show();
      $(this).css({
        'height': 'auto',
        'display': 'block'
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="u-address-fields">
  <select size="15" multiple="multiple" class="showUniOgrp" id="u-address">
    <optgroup class="og-swe" data-opt="qq" label="Swedish Cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="og-ger" data-opt="qq" label="German Cars">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="og-ita" data-opt="qq" label="Italian Cars">
      <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
      <option value="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="my-address-fields">
  <select size="15" multiple="multiple" class="showUniOgrp" id="m-address">

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code you're working with? I'd like to try and reproduce your problem in Safari.

Comment: Question Updated thanks for Prompt replay

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna need a third select with all the optgroups and options which is hidden. You can use it in different ways to achieve what you want but here's one way:

You have all the info in the hidden select (`#h-address`) and once an option is selected you add a class to it (`.slctd`) and if unselected you remove the class. Then populate the two visible selects and remove undesired parts from each.

```js
$.each($('#h-address > optgroup'), function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#u-address');
});

$('#u-address').dblclick(function() {
  $.each($('#u-address option:selected'), function() {
    $('#hidden-fields option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').addClass('slctd');
    showFields();
  });
});

$('#m-address').dblclick(function() {
  $.each($('#m-address option:selected'), function() {
    $('#hidden-fields option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').removeClass('slctd');
    showFields();
  });
});

function showFields() {
  $('#u-address').empty();
  $('#m-address').empty();
  $.each($('#h-address > optgroup'), function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#u-address');
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#m-address');
  });
  $('#u-address option.slctd').remove();
  $('#m-address option:not(.slctd)').remove();

  $.each($('.showUniOgrp > optgroup'), function() {
    if ($(this).html().trim() === "") {
      $(this).remove(); //or detach()
    }
  });
}
```

```css
select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

#hidden-fields {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="u-address-fields">
  <select size="15" multiple="multiple" class="showUniOgrp" id="u-address"></select>
</div>

<div class="my-address-fields">
  <select size="15" multiple="multiple" class="showUniOgrp" id="m-address"></select>
</div>

<div id="hidden-fields">
  <select size="15" multiple="multiple" class="showUniOgrp" id="h-address">
   <optgroup class="og-swe" data-opt="qq" label="Swedish Cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="og-ger" data-opt="qq" label="German Cars">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="og-ita" data-opt="qq" label="Italian Cars">
      <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
      <option value="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

Haven't tested on Safari, but it should work.